# CSS- background color doesn't fill to top of scrolling div

Tags: css, background, scrollbar

I have a div (sub area of page with scroll bar) that has some text, an image and a table.
The background color defined for the div -

```
<div style="background-color: white">
```

does not fill the area to the top, the top arrow of the scroll bar is above the area filled with the background color (by about the width of one line).  Adding a br at the top fixes it, but moves stuff too far down.

I read two potential solutions.  One suggested I set a fixed height for the div.  That would require changing the height by trial-and-error every time I changed the content of the page. Next.  The other suggestion said to add this at the end, just before the /div -

```
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

but that has no effect.

There are several different pages that get loaded into the scrolling area, using SSI's, and some of those included pages use divs, and some of those are floats and some absolutes.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT

Adding the following, which I didn't realize was needed with the "clear", still doesn't work

```
<style type="text/css">
.clear {
clear:both;
height:1px;
overflow:hidden;}
</style>
```

Ad

Comment: Not sure if you just copied this wrong, but there is a typo: `<div style="background-color: white>` requires an ending quote: `<div style="background-color: white">`

Comment: The example code is full of errors, incompletions, etc. Can you point us to a page?

Comment: As stated, we need more info here. The suggestion you got was to make sure the DIV clears all floats. However a class all by itself is useless unless you've also declared .clear {clear: both} in your css.

Comment: I fixed the two code typos. I'm not using CSS of the style { }, but rather the declarations are in the <div ... ... > Where would a clear:both go using the syntax form I'm using? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just wrote this up and it seems to keep the background color no matter how much content you put in it...

```
<div style='background:#abc;overflow:auto;'>
    <p>a bunch of content goes here</p>
</div>
```

you can, of course, set a height to that but more likely it would be in some div wrapper...

Comment: Adding "overflow:auto" to the div solves the problem. Thanks.
I'm using "background-color" - not "background" - interchangeable?

Comment: Yea, background will let you do all background properties in a single statement. The first piece is the color. Thus, as long as you aren't declaring other background properties, background:#fff will function the same as background-color:#fff